# Can I display XML from a variable in through setContentView?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to transform an XML file to Android layout XML through XSLT. So far I got this working, it's returning valid XML. I want this output to be displayed via setContentView (or if this isn't possible, I would like to add Views to a ViewFlipper. So far I haven't been succesfull and I also cannot find any information on this topic.

This is my code:

```
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(projectFile); //a XML file on the SD card
Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.session));
TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);

OutputStream output = new StringOutputStream();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
trans.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

output.toString() returns the transformed XML in a String format, so far everything works! But how can I use this XML in my layout? 
I've tried the following approaches:

```
setContentView(output);
```

and:

```
projectFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.projectFlipper);
projectFlipper.addView(output);
```

I've tried to cast the variable, but I've been stuck for quite a while now. What am I overlooking? Or is there no possible way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, view are created via XML files using [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). However, as said in the javadoc of this class :

> **Important :** For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily
>   on pre-processing of XML files that is
>   done at build time. Therefore, it is
>   not currently possible to use
>   LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser
>   over a plain XML file at runtime.

So, as you see, it's impossible to dynamically use an XML file to create a new view. However, you should be able to translate your "transformation" logic in order to create programmatically your screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. All the resources are compiled and added to the project apk. What u can do is manually parse the xml and create views on the run.

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you have any experience with this? I have to parse a large document 500+ lines, what is the best way to do this? DOM, SAX or pullparser?

Comment: SAX is always a first choice due to its performance. But in this case since you will need to know the view nesting properly DOM will be better i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can let XSLT build the code for you, so you can dynamic generate the Views

Look for inspiration at:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0201-xslt.html